# Access Instance in main.js from a logout button in vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, keycloak, mutation

I use keycloak-js to authenticate my vue.js like this (taken from there: https://www.keycloak.org/securing-apps/vue), it´s my `main.js`:

```
import { store } from "./store/store";

let keycloak = Keycloak(initOptions);

keycloak.init({ onLoad: initOptions.onLoad }).then((auth) => {
  if (!auth) {
    window.location.reload();
  } else {
    console.log("Authenticated");
    new Vue({
      vuetify, router, store,
      render: h => h(App,  { props: { keycloak: keycloak } })
    }).$mount('#app')

  }

  const decoded = VueJwtDecode.decode(keycloak.token)
  const roles = decoded.realm_access.roles
  store.commit("storeRoles", roles)

//Token Refresh
  setInterval(() => {
    if(store.state.userData.logged_out) { ### done in vuex
      keycloak.logout()
    } else {
      keycloak.updateToken(70).then((refreshed) => {
        if (refreshed) {
          console.log('Token refreshed' + refreshed);
        } else {
          console.log('Token not refreshed, valid for '
            + Math.round(keycloak.tokenParsed.exp + keycloak.timeSkew - new Date().getTime() / 1000) + ' seconds');
        }
      }).catch(() => {
        console.log('Failed to refresh token');
      });
    }
  }, 2000)

}).catch(() => {
  console.log("Authenticated Failed");
});
```

I currently commit a mutation in my store to handle this via a button.

```
if(store.state.userData.logged_out) { ### done in vuex
    keycloak.logout()
}

## Handles by a button in my view
this.$store.commit("logout", true)
```

This seems to be a bit hacky and I have to wait 2 seconds before my user actually gets logged out. Is there a way to directly access this keycloak instance from a component?

Comment: Use $root to make keycloak instance accessible from any vue scope or if you want it scoped, you can assign only logout method to Vue.mixin (ofc before Vue init and where keycloak is initialized)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it by adding the keycloak instance to the Vue.prototype (thanks @augstin gorni for the hint)

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/adding-instance-properties.html

```
let keycloak = Keycloak(initOptions);
Vue.prototype.$keycloak = keycloak
```

Now it´s globally accessible

```
logout() {
  this.$keycloak.logout()
}
```

}

Comment: Thank you for this, I read one or two solutions as to how to logout, they all suggest that I should invoke a url(That solution is for java only). I suspected  that information was wrong and was looking for a way of passing the keycloak object between my main page and child component

Comment: glad it helped, that always remembers me not to just delete the question, but to answer it yourself if you find something helpful.

Answer (score 0):

In Vue 3 you can use like below;

```
  app.config.globalProperties.$keycloak = keycloak;
```